# Instance variable in stateless session bean

Tags: session, variables, javabeans, instance, stateless

I have a stateless session bean which has an instance variable and two public methods.Below is pseudo code of it.

```
private int instanceVar;

public void methodA(int x) {
    instanceVar = x;
}

public void methodB() {
    print instanceVar;
}
```

Both the methods are called one after another from the client. The client code and stateless session bean are deployed on Websphere. Its observed that the value of instanceVar printed from methodB is same as in methodA when its a single instance of Application Server or a cluster having 2 Application servers. But in an environment having 3 Application servers, the value of instanceVar printed contains an older value.
Can anyone explain this behavior for me?

Thanks in Advance!

Regards,
Sudhu

Answer (score 0):

Even on a single application server, the EJB container may create multiple instances of the stateless session bean. Therefore using an instance attribute as shown in your pseudo code will never be guaranteed to give the expected result.